# I get an EADDRINUSE error when trying to start my project with pm2

Tags: node.js, npm, server, pm2

I get the following error when running 'pm2 start project.json' in my project.

```
port: 3000 }
0|serv | Tue, 08 Sep 2020 03:14:18 GMT app LoadSettingFromRedis: loaded
0|serv | { Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:3000
0|serv |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1360:14)
0|serv |     at listenInCluster (net.js:1401:12)
0|serv |     at doListen (net.js:1510:7)
0|serv |     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:142:11)
0|serv |     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
0|serv |   errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|serv |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|serv |   syscall: 'listen',
0|serv |   address: '127.0.0.1',
0|serv |   port: 3000 }
0|serv | Tue, 08 Sep 2020 03:15:08 GMT app LoadSettingFromRedis: loaded
0|serv | Tue, 08 Sep 2020 03:20:43 GMT app LoadSettingFromRedis: loaded
```

When I check what process is listening on port 3000, I get node. I kill this process, but it still doesn't solve the issue. Does anyone know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your port is already in use. Try killing port with following command

```
sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:3000)
```

if that not works try following

```
sudo lsof -i tcp:3000   // this will return some PIDs 
sudo kill -9 [your pid to remove]
```

Then run `pm2 start` command again